# Why can't I start a QThread on a signal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I want to start a QThread when another one starts, but it doesn't work.

main.cpp snippet

```
Worker stat_worker;
stat_worker.moveToThread(stat_worker.stat_thread);

Worker some;
some.moveToThread(some.somethread);
QObject::connect(stat_worker.stat_thread, SIGNAL(started()), some.somethread, SLOT(start()));
QObject::connect(some.somethread, SIGNAL(started()), &some, SLOT(print_some()));
stat_worker.stat_thread->start();
```

worker.h

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker();

    QThread *stat_thread = new QThread;
    QThread *somethread = new QThread;
signals:
//some signals
    void start_thread();
public slots:
//some slots
    void print_some();
    void somethread_starter();
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

worker.cpp related function

```
void Worker::print_some()
{
    qInfo() << "-somethread started() signal arrived!";
}
```

When I tried starting a thread with clicking a pushbutton it didn't work either.

Even creating a slot which starts the thread:

```
QObject::connect(stat_worker.stat_thread, &QThread::started, &some, &Worker::somethread_starter);

void Worker::somethread_starter()
{
    qInfo() << "-I got started by another thread!";
    somethread->start();
}
```

or a signal that is emitted on starting the other thread:

```
void Worker::wip_status(){
    emit start_thread();
}

QObject::connect(stat_worker.stat_thread, &QThread::started, &stat_worker, &Worker::wip_status);
QObject::connect(&stat_worker, &Worker::start_thread, &some, &Worker::somethread_starter);
```

work.

Thanks in advance for replying to my post.

Comment: Have you tried using the modern signal connecting syntax which detects typos at compile time?

Comment: @ Alan Birtles: Wait, I think I already use it. You mean it writes in the "Application Output" tab when there is a problem connecting.

Comment: If you use [Qt5 signals](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), there are compile time errors when signature of a slot is not matching. So, you won't see them in the "Application Output" but in the "Build Output" and are not able to even start your application. This is in opposition to the old Qt signals where non-matching slots couldn't be detected before runtime. Hence, Qt5 signals should be preferred whenever possible.

Comment: After Edit: That's not the way Qt5 signals are used. Please, have a look to into the tutorial link I provided. ;-)

Comment: Please, try: `QObject::connect(stat_worker.stat_thread, &QThread::started, some.somethread, &QThread::start);` instead.

Comment: @Scheff: Thank you for your help. I tried that, it gives me: "use of undeclared identifier 'stat_thread' ", "use of undeclared identifier 'somethread' "

Comment: Isn't `somethread` member of `some`? Isn't `some` not of type `Worker`?

Comment: @Scheff: Sorry, I made a mistake. I needed to put "QThread::". But this gives me: "C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qobject.h:255: error: C2338: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible."

Comment: _C2338: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible._ Here you are. :-) You could fix this by a lambda to make the slot compatible to the signal, or just define a member function with matching signature in `Worker` which is used as "trampoline".

Comment: Try to add `void startSome() { some_thread->start(); }` to `class Worker` and use `QObject::connect(stat_worker.stat_thread, &QThread::started, &some, &Worker::startSome);` to connect it.

Comment: Btw. That's another advantage of Qt5 signals: You don't need to remark slots additionally (like before). Just every member function or function with matching signature can be used.

Comment: I assume, `QThread::start()` is incompatible due to its argument. (The default value doesn't help - it still has wrong signature.)

Comment: @Scheff Please don't advise to use Qt connections with Lambdas in a threaded scope, or at least mention it should still be used with an explicit context object. Otherwise thread affinity is ignored, and further havoc awaits.

Comment: I edited the question, it still doesn't work somehow.

Comment: @Ext3h You are right. To make it working with lambdas and threads, you have to care about to provide an additional context. I remembered this and provided the other work-around with the "trampoline" member function which OP preferred (for my luck). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce OPs issue with my own MCVE (which is just a bit shorter).

```
#include <QtWidgets>

struct Worker: QObject {
  QString name;
  QThread qThread;

  Worker(const QString &name): name(name)
  {
    moveToThread(&qThread);
    connect(&qThread, &QThread::finished, this, &Worker::reportFinished);
  }

  void start()
  {
    qDebug() << "Start" << name;
    qThread.start();
  }

  void reportFinished()
  {
    qDebug() << "Exit" << name;
  }
};

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  Worker worker1("worker 1");
  Worker worker2("worker 2");
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&worker1.qThread, &QThread::started, &worker2, &Worker::start);
  worker1.start();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
Start "worker 1"
```

This what OP observed. So, what?

- the `worker1.qThread.started` signal is connected to the `worker2.start` slot
- the `worker1` is started
- `worker2` doesn't seem to start.

What made me suspicious: `moveToThread()`.

The intention is to associate the `Worker` object with its member `QThread`.

What I'm not sure about: Is this possible before the `QThread` is started?

To check this out, I commented the `moveToThread()`:

```
  Worker(const QString &name): name(name)
  {
    //moveToThread(&qThread);
    connect(&qThread, &QThread::finished, this, &Worker::reportFinished);
  }
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
Start "worker 1"
Start "worker 2"
```

The reason why I commented the `moveToThread()`:
The call of `qThread::start()` should happen in the context of the main application (thread).
So, moving `worker2` to its `QThread` means that the signal is sent to the event loop of `worker2.qThread` – which is actually not yet started.

Hence, the event cannot be processed.

The `moveToThread()` should be done later – e.g. in reaction of the `started()` signal:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

struct Worker: QObject {
  QString name;
  QThread qThread;

  Worker(const QString &name): name(name)
  {
    connect(&qThread, &QThread::started, this, &Worker::moveThisToThread);
    connect(&qThread, &QThread::finished, this, &Worker::reportFinished);
  }

  void start()
  {
    qDebug() << "Start" << name;
    qThread.start();
  }

  void moveThisToThread()
  {
    moveToThread(&qThread);
    qDebug() << name << "associated to its thread, from now.";
  }

  void reportFinished()
  {
    qDebug() << "Exit" << name;
  }
};

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  Worker worker1("worker 1");
  Worker worker2("worker 2");
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&worker1.qThread, &QThread::started, &worker2, &Worker::start);
  worker1.start();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
Start "worker 1"
"worker 1" associated to its thread, from now.
Start "worker 2"
"worker 2" associated to its thread, from now.
```

---

**Bonus Question:**

> So does that mean "QThread::start" is useless as receiver of a signal?

No, it's not. Even if there is no existing signal with that signature (I know about) the application developer is free to “invent” one.

However, remembering that Qt5 doesn't actually require explicitly marked `SLOT`s to use them for signals, a more obvious answer may be found in the past:

With Qt4 signals, the `QThread::start` slot could have been connected to the `QThread::started` signal directly. (The default value of the one and only parameter in `QThread::start` becomes effective then.)

As I have no experience with Qt4 signals (I started with Qt5), I modified my sample code to prove me right:

```
  QObject::connect(&worker1.qThread, SIGNAL(started()), &worker2.qThread, SLOT(start()));
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
Start "worker 1"
"worker 1" associated to its thread, from now.
"worker 2" associated to its thread, from now.
```

The `Start "worker 2"` isn't emitted anymore as `worker1.started()` calls `worker2.qThread.start()` directly, now.

So, with Qt4 signals the original code of OP might have been worked.
It wasn't the incompatibility of signal and slot (as somebody guessed) which caused the issue but probably the above described `moveToThread()` issue (as well) which didn't make it work satisfyingly.

Comment: I still have one question: So does that mean "QThread::start" is useless as receiver of a signal? How can this slot be used properly? except qThread->start();

Comment: Again, thank you a lot! I have a feeling this isn't just going to help me, but other people in the future too.