# QThread is not stoping

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, worker

It was my first attempt to create a thread in qt but unfortunately it isn't stopping. This is how my code look like.

// Worker class

```cpp
    class Worker : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    public slots:
        void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
            QString result;
            forever{
                if(QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()){
                    printf("true");
                    return;
                }else{
                    if(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()){
                        cout<<parameter.toStdString();
                    }
                }
            }
            emit resultReady(result);
        }
    
    signals:
        void resultReady(const QString &result);
    };
```

// Controller class

```cpp
    class Controller : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        QThread workerThread;
    public:
        Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr):QObject(parent) {
            Worker *worker = new Worker;
            worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
            connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
            connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
            workerThread.start();
        }
        ~Controller() {
            workerThread.quit();
            workerThread.wait();
        }
    public slots:
        void stop(){
            workerThread.requestInterruption();
        }
    signals:
        void operate(const QString &);
    };
```

The forever loop isn't stopping when stop function is called.Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `QThread::currentThread()` call in `doWork()` function returns the `workerThread`?

Comment: I'm not sure but when i remove else condition it prints true and finishes the thread. Hope you understand what i said.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755238/4149835 how one can stop threads.

Comment: yeah i'll try that

Comment: Stopping a worker thread is also discussed here if this might be interesting
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539161/how-to-stop-cancel-a-worker-job-using-the-cancel-button-of-a-qprogressdialog/64551400#64551400

Comment: Can you post your main to see how you are using these classes please?

Comment: thank's @Pat.ANDRIA your post really solved my problem I'll write an answer soon showing what was the problem thanks.